# selenium browser driver decode error in Chinese

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

because of Chinese, browser decodes the page source error, and I can not decode to the right content by Python
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3seHf.png)

but for the browser, it displays correctly...

how do I decode the page source to get the right content?

[the api url](http://data.stats.gov.cn/easyquery.htm?m=QueryData&dbcode=fsjd&rowcode=zb&colcode=sj&wds=%5B%7B%22wdcode%22%3A%22reg%22%2C%22valuecode%22%3A%22350000%22%7D%5D&dfwds=%5B%7B%22wdcode%22%3A%22zb%22%2C%22valuecode%22%3A%22A0301%22%7D%5D&k1=1556435180173)
[the page url](http://data.stats.gov.cn/easyquery.htm?cn=E0102)

here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/ug/Desktop/bin/chromedriver")

# the url is the `api url`       
driver.get("http://data.stats.gov.cn/easyquery.htm?m=QueryData&dbcode=fsjd&rowcode=zb&colcode=sj&wds=%5B%7B%22wdcode%22%3A%22reg%22%2C%22valuecode%22%3A%22350000%22%7D%5D&dfwds=%5B%5D&k1=1555920886106")

driver.page_source
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: don't post screenshots of code

Comment: Usually you shouldn't need to scrape an api endpoint, and it's the same in this case too. It looks like a json object to me and you don't need selenium for it. I think `json.loads()` should work

Comment: with `json.loads`, it shows like this:

```
     {'cname': '2017骞寸\ue0c7鍥涘\ue11c搴�',
      'code': '2017D',
      'dotcount': 4,
      'exp': '',
      'ifshowcode': False,
      'memo': '',
      'name': '2017骞寸\ue0c7鍥涘\ue11c搴�',
      'nodesort': '1',
      'sortcode': 8,
      'tag': '',
      'unit': ''}],
    'wdcode': 'sj',
    'wdname': '鏃堕棿'}]
```,

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by executing javascript.

first, I use `driver.get("http://data.stats.gov.cn")`,
next, `driver.execute_script('$.ajax...')`, and set the return as the page content,

now, the page source was decoded correctly...

I think it's ajax worked